# Who last modified file?

Tags: linux

Is there a way to tell who (which user) last modified the last file in Linux (RHEL)?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42234/display-a-files-history-list-of-users-that-have-modified-a-file is more recent and has some answers

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is far from reliable, but if we are talking about shell access, you could cross-reference the file's modification time with the users logged in at that time (`last`) and then check their ~/.bash_history (or equivalent) for editing commands. Even `grep -H filename /home/*/.bash_history` could give you a starting point.

Answer (score 18):

No, there is no reliable way to discover that.

The `stat` command shows you everything that's known about a file (except the actual contents).  You can add the -Z option to get some SELinux info; but none of that tells you who modified the file last.

Comment: Yeah but no other tools to dig out ?